# How can I connect two routers using WDS?

Tags: ip, router, wireless-networking, mac-address

I have two wireless routers D-Link DIR-615 Wireless N 300 Router and JioFi 2,
as the JioFi 2 don't have an expected coverage i was planning to extend the range, as i have an unused wireless router i thought of connecting both, I had tried the WDS option but it was in vain.
JioFi 2 is the network providing router and D-Link acts as a range extender, JioFi 2 is WPA2-PSK password protected. I had also tried disabling the WPS in the D-Link router and also the passwords.

Steps I followed are,

1. configured the D-Link router to the same network segment.
2. Disabled DHCP in D-Link router.
3. Disabled WPS in D-Link Router.
4. selected the same channel as of JioFi router.
5. copied the MAC id of JioFi router to D-Link.
6. Disabled security and WPS in JioFi router.

Did I miss any steps ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to configure both routers into WDS mode and each one needs to know the other's MAC id. (Unless the unconfigured router supports and has enabled passive WDS, which is very rare.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your JioFi 2 is a mobile router that does not have a wired Ethernet interface and it cannot be connected to a wired network. So you probably would want to implement a wireless connection between your two routers and in such setup DIR-615 would act as a wireless repeater.

Unfortunately it's not possible to do it with factory firmware in DIR-615 as it does not support working in repeater (or WDS) mode.

As another solution you may try to install one of many open-source firmware solutions available into your DIR-615, but it can be tricky and produce unpredictable results if you make something wrong.

My advice is to buy a Wi-Fi extender and set it up to extend your wireless network. There are lots of such devices available and it is possible to find one that fits into your budget.

P.S. Changing security parameters (turn off WPS and wireless security) is not related to your problem and not needed in this case.

P.P.S. The manual for DIR-615 is here: http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/-/media/consumer_products/dir/dir-615/manual/dir_615_manual_en_uk.pdf